# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. and install Access Database Engine 2010 don´t work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have trouble when I try to upload an Excel file, I've searched in a lot of places how to solve this, but the solution the give (only install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable) doesn´t work for me. I have VS2017 and I've installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, I´m kinda new doing this so I donn´t know what I´m missing.

Thanks

Comment: what are you using What program do you want to upload the excel file to? What is your method?

Answer (score 0):

a pleasure to greet you, an hour ago I had the same problem, the only thing I did was download both versions (both the 32-bit and the 64-bit version) and the first thing I did was install the 64-bit version of normal way, downloading from the official page, but I installed the 32-bit version from Command Prompt with the following code:

CD: [path]/AccessDataEngine.exe /passive

in this way I managed to solve that error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).